# What is the best way to hide a backface during a transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following element and transform happening in CSS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9RJh.gif

What would be the best way of hiding the blinking "LED" when the flap is open?

I've tried a couple of ways with timed replacements and the like, but I cannot seem to get this to work. I couldn't get `backface-visibility: hidden;` to work either.

Here's the CSS I am using:

```
transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(-115deg);
```

***Any*** ideas would be appreciated.

Many thanks!!

Edit: Updated with JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/873hgwsv/

Comment: How about create another div and set its `z-index` lower, when you perform the animation you apply that animation to the new div too?

Comment: The extra element just shows on the other side as well.

Comment: I created an animation with CSS keyframes you can take a look at [here](https://codepen.io/vpvpgk/pen/XWWmoGm?editors=0100). The idea is change the div appearance at keyframe 78.261% (90 / 115)

Comment: Adding `backface-visibility: hidden` to `.bar-cover` seems to work

Comment: @KostasSiabanis - That seems to hide the entire element as well as mess up the animation? https://jsfiddle.net/farL24hw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
I had to add `transform-style: preserve-3d !important;` as well as the backface attribute.

Hope this helps someone else!